# What is the most efficient way to bulk insert negative credit amounts into my transaction table for all users in my users table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Database: MySQL version 5.5.38 
  Connections using mysqli

Server code base: PHP 5.4.30

I need some advice on the most efficient way to bulk insert records into a table based on the contents of another table.

Our system has "credits".  "Credits" can be bought and transferred.  Credits expire over time (you lose X per day) and are calculated by getting the sum of the CreditTotal column in the transactions table.

I would like to insert a transaction with a quantity of 1 and a credit value of -X for every user in the system which is triggered by a cron task on our server.

This needs to be run as a daily task so that users can be notified in advance if their credit is getting low.  I could potentially have a very large number of Users of the system.

Table 1: transactions

```
Field name      Type        Allow nulls?        Key     Default value       Extras   
TransKey    bigint(20)  No  Primary     NULL    auto_increment
OfferKey    bigint(20)  Yes     None    NULL    
ProdKey     bigint(20)  Yes     None    NULL    
Credit  bigint(20)  Yes     None    NULL    
Qty     bigint(20)  Yes     None    NULL    
TotalPrice  decimal(10,2)   Yes     None    NULL    
CreditTotal     bigint(20)  Yes     None    0   
Price   decimal(10,2)   Yes     None    NULL    
TranDteTme  timestamp   No  Indexed     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
UserKey     bigint(20)  Yes     Indexed     NULL        



Field name      Type        Allow nulls?        Key     Default value       Extras   
UserKey     bigint(20)  No  Primary     NULL    auto_increment
```

What would be the best way to efficiently do this, and are there any obvious pitfalls that I could avoid?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at the [MySQL event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) rather than CRON/PHP.
For this sort of large scale batch operations you might want to consider writing a [MySQL Function or Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).